# Syntax error in SQL statement "WITH" keyword

Tags: java, sql, h2

```
jdbc:h2:mem:request_no;MODE=Oracle
```

We are using the h2 version 1.3.171 with windows 7 (64 bit) and jdk 1.7.0_25.

When we try to run the SQL statement:

```sql
WITH TMP1 AS (SELECT col1 FROM table1) SELECT TMP1.col1 FROM TMP1
```

We are getting the below exception:

```sql
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
"WITH TMP1 AS[*] (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE) 
  SELECT TMP1.REQUEST_NO FROM TMP1";
expected "., ("; SQL statement:
WITH TMP1 AS (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE) 
  SELECT TMP1.REQUEST_NO FROM TMP1 [42001-171]
```

SQL statement is fine as we are able to execute it successfully via SQL Developer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: H2 does not support regular common table expressions, it only supports recursive CTEs: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the columns as part of the CTE definition:

```
WITH TMP1(REQUEST_NO) AS
      (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE
      )
SELECT TMP1.REQUEST_NO
FROM TMP1;
```

I think some databases require explicit column lists when using `with`.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Gordon Linoff ...I was able to run the query as per your solution.

Comment: On a Similar Story, I have also added another TMP2 and was not able to run the query... Could you please help me on this also?         WITH TMP1(REQUEST_NO) AS (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE )       SELECT TMP1.REQUEST_NO FROM TMP1;                                WITH TMP1(REQUEST_NO) AS                                      (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE), TMP2(AGENT) AS (SELECT AGENT FROM AGENT_TAB) SELECT TMP2.AGENT FROM TMP2;        Thank you for your kind help!!!

Comment: @Anteneh . . . If you have another question, you should post it as a question not a comment.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have also created a new question and can you please look in to that...here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722561/syntax-error-in-sql-statement-with-keyword-throwing-exception    Thanks a lot!!!