# Syntax error in SQL statement “WITH” keyword throwing exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, h2

I have also added another TMP2 and was not able to run the query... Could you please help me on this query? I am using Oracle 11g.

```
WITH TMP1(REQUEST_NO) AS (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE) 
SELECT TMP1.REQUEST_NO FROM TMP1;

WITH TMP1(REQUEST_NO) AS
  (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE),
  TMP2(AGENT) AS (SELECT AGENT FROM AGENT_TAB)
SELECT TMP2.AGENT FROM TMP2;
```

The exception I got is :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
Syntax error in SQL statement "WITH TMP1(REQUEST_NO) AS (SELECT REQUEST_NO FROM QUOTE),
[*]TMP2(AGENT) AS (SELECT AGENT FROM AGENT_TAB) SELECT TMP2.AGENT FROM TMP2 "; expected "(,
SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
```

The query is fine in sql developer but not working in the Junit tests.  jdbc:h2:mem:request_no;MODE=Oracle
We are using the h2 version 1.3.171 with windows 7 (64 bit) and jdk 1.7.0_25.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports the WITH clause, but it is looks like H2 does not support it:
[H2 SQL grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select)

I would transform the query in the with part to the main query.